# Sandbox Account for Digital Goods

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I have a PayPal account lets say 'myemail@mycompany.com'. Within the account there are two sandbox accounts one for seller and the other one for buyer. From what I have read I need to enable my account for accepting payment on digital goods.

May I know on which account I need to enable this (PayPal / Sandbox account) ? Because I believe I have enable it on my PayPal account but I still get the same error as follow

`You are not signed up to accept payment for digitally delivered goods.`

**Updated**

The test sandbox seller account email is ucmasS_1361258557_biz@ucmas.com. By the way, is it still safe to reuse the same email in production environment ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to enable this on the test sandbox seller account.  If you can provide the email address for your test sandbox seller account, I can enable this feature on your account from my end.

Comment: I have enabled Digital Goods on your sandbox account.  If you still get an error, can you provide the API call that you are sending along with the API response you get back.

Comment: I am able to login and made payment (almost). After I press the "pay now" button the page redirects me to `https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/MyNewApp/home?token=EC-41658863H3601431S&PayerID=F3G3JHG2BG2K6` which says `Please login to use the PayPal Sandbox features.` Any idea ?

Comment: Try closing out of browser, clear all cookies, cache, and history.  Then try logging into developer.paypal.com again and run the test.  Also try using Firefox or Chrome if you are using IE. There have been a few more issues with IE than the other 2 browsers.

Comment: @PP_MTS_Chad ... can you enable it for me too? admin_api1.charlesmudy.com

Comment: @PP_MTS_Chad can you enable that for me too please? christian3@cvj.se

Answer (score 1):

I managed to change an Express Checkout sandbox account to a "PayPal Digital Goods (Express Checkout)" account by hitting the following URL while logged in on the sandbox account:

https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_product-go&product=additional_payment&signup_profile=dg

This is a bit reverse engineered (after visiting www.paypal.com/digitalgoods and following the link to enable a digital goods account put "sandbox." in front of paypal.com) but it looks like it works.